# Silverlight NumericUpDown inside Datagrid strange behaviour

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have a DataGrid that has a column containing a NumericUpDown control and have come across some very annoying behaviour. If the user sets the value of the control and then continues on the cell content surrounding the control, the value of the control seems to reset. This is proving to be especially annoying as this control is working in conjunction with a value "pool" in that the amount available in total for all rows is dependent on another value outside the datagrid. It's not as simple as using the MaxValue attribute of the control, as the total chosen needs to span across all the rows. I'm capturing the ValueChanging event and cancelling if there is nothing available from the pool, however this pool is incorrect due to the buggy behaviour of clicking outside the NumericUpDown. Has anyone else experienced something similar and is there any workarounds?

**UPDATE #1:**
I've noticed that this behaviour only happens if I hook onto the ValueChanging/Changed events. If I don't handle these events, then the weird reset behaviour does not happen when clicking just outside the control.

**UPDATE #2:**
I've zeroed in on the resetting issue which was due to my code. However, there is still the problem of clicking the cell area surrounding NumericUpDown causing the ValueChanging/Changed events to fire. I've also noticed that if I debug and put a breakpoint on these events, they continue to fire until I remove the breakpoints.